# how to avoid multiple alerts after condition is met?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I have a strategy when condition is met only one alert should trigger and not on every candle. i would like to automate trade. code is below

```
if longsignal
    strategy.entry(id="Long", direction=strategy.long)
    alert(message = 'long entry',alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe set the pyramiding to 1 from the strategy properties tab and/or do something like this

```
if longsignal and not longsignal[1]
    strategy.entry(id="Long", direction=strategy.long)
    alert(message = 'long entry',alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
```